# Using custom shell script as docker entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I’m trying to use docker-compose to bring up a container. As an **ENTRYPOINT**, that container has a simple bash script that I wrote. Now, when I try to bring up the container in any of the below ways:

- `docker-compose up`
- `docker-compose up foo`

it doesn’t complete. i.e., trying to attach (`docker exec -i -t $1 /bin/bash`) to the running container, fails with:

> Error response from daemon: Container xyz is restarting, wait until the container is running.

I tried playing around with putting commands in the background. That didn’t work.

**my-script.sh**

```
cmd1 &
cmd2 &&
...
cmdn &
```

I also tried *i)* with and without `entrypoint: /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/my-script.sh` and *ii)* with and without the `tty: true` option. No dice.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.foo
    ...
    tty: true
    entrypoint: /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/my-script.sh
```

Also tried just a manual docker build / run cycle. And (without launching `/bin/sh` in the **ENTRYPOINT** ) the run just exits.

```
$ docker build ... .
$ docker run -it ... 
... shell echos commands here, then exits
$
```

I'm sure its something simple. What's the solution here?

Comment: When your shell script terminates also the container will terminate. So putting commands in the background is not a good idea.

Comment: @Henry I tried with and without putting my last command in the background. But it turns out that my last command should be a blocking one: `touch 1.txt && tail -f 1.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to put something infinite to keep running your container in background,like you can `tail -f application.log` or anything like this so that even if you exit from your container bash it keeps running in background

you do not need to do `cmd1 & cmd2 &&...cmdn &` just place one command like this `touch 1.txt && tail -f 1.txt` as a last step in your `my-script.sh`. It will keep running your container.
One thing also you need to change is `docker run -it -d` `-d` will start container with background mode.If you want to go inside your container than `docker exec -it container_name/id bash` debug the issue and exit.It will still keep your container running until you stop with `docker stop container_id/name`
Hope this help.
Thank you!

Comment: Ok, yes. Putting in a blocking command (`touch 1.txt && tail -f 1.txt`) fixes that problem. Cheers all.

Answer (score 4):

Your `entrypoint` in your `docker-compose.yml` only needs to be

```
entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/my-script.sh
```

Just add `#! /bin/sh` to the top of the script to specify the shell you want to use.

You also need to add `exec "$@"` to the bottom of your entrypoint script or else it will exit immediately, which will terminate the container.

Comment: The exit immediately part really came in handy to perform error handling in a script of mine. Thank you.